# Sum of n consecutive items in a collection without for loops

Tags: c++, std

I an looking how to remove my for loops to compute the sum of the n consecutive items in a collection.

> Example: for the collection {1,2,1,3,2} and n=3 (where n is the
>   number of consecutive items to process), the result would be
>   {0,0,4,6,6}
>
> **{1,2,1,3,2} and n=3 produces {0,0,4,6,6}**

To determine the sum of two consecutive items, I understand I can do this:

```
std::adjacent_difference(std::begin(collection), 
                          std::end(collection), 
                         std::begin(adjacent_sum), 
[](const int x, const int y) { return std::abs(x - y); });
```

But to determine the sum of n consecutive items, I am stuck by the fact that algorithms like std::transform process the value while I need the index. Should I use index as variable outside of the algorith to maintain a state.

Here a complete example that compiles with Visual Studio 2019:

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <numeric>    
#include <vector>

// Compute the sum of the n consecutive items
// Ex: {1,2,1,3,2} and n=3
// result: {0,0,4,6,6}
std::vector<int> adjacent_difference_n(const std::vector<int> collection, const size_t num_consecutive_items) 
{
    std::vector<int> result {};
    const auto collection_size = collection.size();

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < num_consecutive_items - 1; idx++)
    {
        result.emplace_back(0);
    }

    if (collection_size >= num_consecutive_items)
    {
        // For each element starting at num_consecutive_items
        for (auto idx = num_consecutive_items - 1; idx < collection_size; idx++)
        {
            // Compute the sum of the previous num_consecutive_item
            // Loop includes the current item
            auto sum = 0;
            auto prev_idx = idx - (num_consecutive_items - 1); 
            while (prev_idx <= idx)
            {
                sum += collection[prev_idx++];                
            }
            result.emplace_back(sum);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> collection = { 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };
    const auto result = adjacent_difference_n(collection, 3);
    for (auto& value : result) std::cout << value << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want to remove "for loops" from your algorithm? Your case sounds like a perfect example of why you would want a for loop: an algorithm that requires state from a certain number of previous iterations. Simply, why?

Comment: I am looking for a more generic way to express the logic instead of for the reader to understand the for loops edge cases that occurs with statements using idx - n - 1 and <= to include the current item.

Comment: Why not just store value `x, y, z` and initialize them to 0. Each loop, you can then assign: `x = y; y = z;` and then `z = arr[i];`. Should be easy to understand, no edge-cases, and allows you to easily calculate the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the inner loop updating the partial sum by just subtracting the first item and adding the new one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

template <class T>
auto partial_sum_n(std::vector<T> const& src, size_t m)
{
    // Initialize the resulting vector with zeroes
    std::vector<T> result(src.size());
    if (m == 0  or  src.size() < m)
        return result;

    auto first = src.cbegin();
    auto it = std::next(first, m);

    // Sum the first elements and assign to the first non zero element
    auto sum = std::accumulate(first, it, T(0));
    auto dest = std::next(result.begin(), m - 1);
    *dest = sum;

    // Fill the rest of the vector 
    std::transform(it, src.cend(),
                   ++dest,
                   [first, sum] (T const& x) mutable {
                       sum += x - *(first++);    // <-- Just update the sum
                       return sum;
                   });

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> collection{ 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };
    const auto result = partial_sum_n(collection, 3);
    for (auto const value : result)
        std::cout << ' ' << value;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution to my problem.

For anyone interested, I use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) and [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

// Compute the sum of the n consecutive items
// Ex: {1,2,1,3,2} and n=3
// result: {0,0,4,6,6}
std::vector<int> adjacent_sum_n(const std::vector<int> collection, const size_t num_consecutive_items)
{
    // Create the result collection with the same size than the specified collection
    const auto collection_size = collection.size();
    std::vector<int> result{};
    result.resize(collection_size);

    // Fill to zero the items that have not enough previous items
    std::fill(begin(result), begin(result) + num_consecutive_items - 1, 0);

    // For each remaining items, compute the sum the n consecutive items
    auto idx = num_consecutive_items - 1;
    std::for_each(begin(result) + idx,
                   end(result),
    [&](auto& value)
    {
        const auto first_item_idx = idx - num_consecutive_items + 1;
        const auto sum = std::accumulate(begin(collection) + first_item_idx,
            begin(collection) + idx + 1,
            0);
        ++idx;
        value = sum;
    });

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> collection = { 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };

    const auto result = adjacent_sum_n(collection, 3);

    for (auto& value : result) std::cout << value << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ummm... in what way is this more clear than a `for` loop?

Comment: I do agree this code may be less clear for anyone who does not know these calls. The goal of replacing the loop is to separate each step of the processing so they are not inter-connected through a loop and hopefully can be understood separately, ie without side effect of edge cases. Does it make sense?